# Page jumps after load

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page jumps back to the top after 1-3 seconds after the page has loaded. 
I start scrolling the second the page has loaded. the it jumps back.
I can not find the problem. Anyone any ideas why is that?

http://vietnam.asiastreetfood.com/vietnamesischer-feuertopf/

Comment: It's a login page for me .. I can't scroll.

Comment: I can't see your problem using Chrome

Comment: there is no login page

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Just click on the "sign in" button

Comment: I see the problem using Chrome

Comment: Hi, a future visitor here from 6 years after this question was posted. Answers to this question actually helped me debug this.

Answer (score 4):

This is your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[placeholder]').placeholder();
});

$(window).load(function() {
    var vWrapWidth  = -$("#wrapper").width()/2;
    var vWrapHeight = -$("#wrapper").height()/2;
           $("#wrapper").css({'margin-left' : vWrapWidth});
           $("#wrapper").css({'margin-top' : vWrapHeight});

    var vCompWidth    = -$(".company a img").width()/2;
           $(".company a img").css({'margin-left' : vCompWidth});
});
```

The part in the `$(window).load(function(){})` won't fire until all of your images are completely rendered, which can take several seconds. The .css changes to your margins are probably causing the jumping behavior.

Comment: so how can i change this. i mean i cannot change the css.

Comment: btw where did you find the script? :)

Comment: Dug around in your header in the chrome developer tools until I found something that looked scriptish :) To change the css without causing jumping, it would need to happen before the `.load` event fires on the window. If you don't need images to be rendered when you change the css, you can put that stuff in the `.ready` callback instead.

Comment: i cannot find that script :) where exactly did you find it? line number or name of file would help maybe :) thanks a lot for your help

Comment: got the problem. it has been a plugin called MapLists. thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me narrow down on my issue. In my case it was this code on an iframe: onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"

Answer (score 1):

A likely culprit is something that does:

```
document.location.href = "#";
```

or

```
document.location.href = "#missinganchor";
```

Where `missinganchor` is an anchor that isn't defined on the page. This will cause the page to *jump* to the top.